# ASP.NET theme: edit by user

Tags: asp.net, css, themes

I'm searching for a demo app that allow user to edit (change items css - color, background, etc. but also change items position and add/delete new elements on page) application theme/css in ASP.NET. 
Any idea of such application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umbraco - a free .NET content management system - might be worth a review, though I'm not sure that this is exactly what you are looking for:

http://umbraco.com/why-umbraco

The above link is not a demo per se, so please defer to another answer if you strictly need a demo, versus an example of a tool that has the functionality you indicated. In addition to the items you menioned, Umbraco allows you to embed your own controls in the CMS, among other great features. I don't have personal experience with it, but colleagues have recommended it to me.